# PHP MySql - How to extract specific records of a query result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that I put in a variable called $myQuery:

```
$myQuery = mysql_query(...);
```

Then I would like to extract the data using a while loop. The thing is that I do not want to start with the first record (first row), but with the second one. I do not manage to find how to do that...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery)) {  
    ???
}
```

Then, later on I would like to use the variables from the first record (first row) of that query. Again I do not find how to do that. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$first_record = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($myQuery)) {  
    if(count($first_record) == 0) {
        $first_record = $row;
    } else {
        // not the first record
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Then you can work on the $array variable as you see fit. You can then help yourself with **count()** and other functions.

For example:

```
$last = count($array);
echo $array[0]['username'];
echo $array[2]['username'];
echo $array[$last - 1]['username'];
```

Hope this helps.